# Using Java Libraries in Android Project

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, libraries

I'd like to use a Java library I wrote in an Android project. I did two things:

1. Add the jar to the build path.

   - In the package explorer now has a Referenced Library folder
   - Compile works
2. I copied the jar into a libs folder within the project

   - Compile works

But the program crashes during runtime for both approaches. The program does not recognize the class I am calling. A `classDefNotFound` is thrown.

I have tried this for various jar files. The ones I write do not work. While downloaded  jars work. Perhaps there is something wrong with the classes I am writing?

Android Code:

```
package com.davidk.androidtest;

import com.davidk.libs.Math;            //<--classDefNotFound is thrown
import com.parse.Parse;                 //<--works
import com.parse.ParseObject;           //<--works

public void pressButtonOnClick(View v){
    int answer = Math.add(1,1);

    answerText.setText(answer);
}

public void pingParseButtonOnClick(View v){
    ParseObject p = new ParseObject("Ping");
    p.put("String", "ping");
    p.saveInBackground();
}
```

`davidk.libs.Math` code:

```
package com.davidk.libs;

public class Math {

    public static int add(int x, int y){

        return x + y;

    }
}
```

Comment: you are using eclipse?. Check if your java build path is configured properly

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Eclipse. Do not try to mess with jars. The easiest way is :

- In your library project, check the `Is Library` in the Android section of the project properties
- In your dependant project, add the library in the same place (Android section). Do not add anything in the "Java build path" section ! (this is the most common mistake)

Answer (score 0):

Each jar file exported contains a manifest file, to which the code tries to refer. In your case, I guess the manifest file is missing or corrupted. To generate the jar without any issues or complications, there are many open source tools available, which will help you to achieve this.

Other possible method is as suggested by @Orabig.

Please visit below link for more.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html